# How to get elements from a specific range out of a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, range

Does anybody have an idea how to get the elements in a list whose values fall within a specific (from - to) range?

I need a loop to check if a list contains elements in a specific range, and if there are any, I need the biggest one to be saved in a variable..

**Example:**

```py
list = [0.5, 0.56, 0.34, 0.45, 0.53, 0.6]

# range (0.5 - 0.58)
# biggest = 0.56
```

Comment: I'd stay away from using built-ins as variable names in your code. `list` is a builtin function in python hence why Green Cloak Guy changed the variable to `lst` in his answer. [Here are all the builtin methods in python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in). Also be aware of the [keywords in python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keyword-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a filtered comprehension to get only those elements in the range you want, then find the biggest of them using the built-in `max()`:

```
lst = [0.5, 0.56, 0.34, 0.45, 0.53, 0.6]
biggest = max([e for e in lst if 0.5 < e < 0.58])
# biggest = 0.56
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to other answers, you can also use `filter` and `lambda`:

```
lst = [0.5, 0.56, 0.34, 0.45, 0.53, 0.6]
biggest = max([i for i in filter(lambda x: 0.5 < x < 0.58, lst)])
```

I suppose a normal if check would be faster, but I'll give this just for completeness.

Also, you should not use `list = ...` as `list` is a built-in in python.

Answer (score -1):

You could also go about it a step at a time, as the approach may aid in debugging.
I used numpy in this case, which is also a helpful tool to put in your tool belt.

This should run as is:

```
import numpy as np

l = [0.5, 0.56, 0.34, 0.45, 0.53, 0.6]

a = np.array(l)

low = 0.5
high = 0.58

index_low = (a < high) 
print(index_low)

a_low = a[index_low]
print(a_low)

index_in_range = (a_low >= low)
print(index_in_range)

a_in_range = a_low[index_in_range]
print(a_in_range)

a_max = a_in_range.max()
print(a_max)
```